# Highlight certain controls when hovering above a button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following case:

There are several list boxes where the user can select something, some text boxes to enter text and several buttons to execute commands.

If a button is not enabled (due to a wrong/missing selection in a list box and/or a wrong entry in a text field), I'd like to show the red error adorner around the elements that needs to be fixed.

I know how I can show the red border when a entry is not correct using Validation rules - but they are not applicable since the fact "is correct" depends on the command the user wants to execute. E.g. to add an element, there is no need for a selected element in a listbox, but if you want to delete one, there needs to be a selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [attached behavior](http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/) on the button itself. Then, hook the [MouseEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MouseLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx) events for the button.

Then all you have to do (when the mouse enters and exits the button) is fill out the validation rules for each control you want to "turn on or off" for the validation box.

Comment: Just to ensure I get you right: You suggest changing the validation rules based on the button I'm hovering over to use the error border as a highlighting? Then each button would have to know about the controls it depends upon (I'd prefer to stay at the view model level and only let the command know about the selected items and texts)...

Comment: Well your validation rules have to be swapped out based on some other field right? The command they are selecting? You could swap them out when the command is selected instead of when they hover the button, which would be a better experience. Either way, if you want dynamic validation, you'll have to change the rules some how. You could always have a true/false validation rule binded to something and have the button hover change that backing property. Maybe your question title isn't actually what you're looking for?

Comment: It doesn't have to be accomplished with validation rules. Some adorner approach might also work.